# XWiki extension : detect event space creation

Tags: java, xwiki

Based on the documentation here we can see that in a xwiki java extension, we can intercept the event UserCreation like that :

https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Observation%20Module%20Local#HWritinganEventListenerinVelocityinaWikipage

```
public void onEvent(Event event, Object source, Object data)
{
    XWikiDocument document = (XWikiDocument) source;
    String wikiName = document.getDocumentReference().getWikiReference().getName();
    DocumentReference userClass = new DocumentReference(wikiName, "XWiki", "XWikiUsers");

    if (document.getXObject(userClass) != null) {
}
```

I want the same thing, but I want to detect the event space creation ( so basically when you add a space( basically a space is the main root page of an article ) in your wiki. But I didn't found any class like XWikiUsers for the space or the page.

It don't want to do it with velocity or groovy but in pure java extension and I have no clue, the doc is very huge but it's hard to found what I' looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, a "space" gets created whenever a page is created under it (either terminal page or `WebHome`).

So you could either:

- do a query each time a page is being created (`DocumentCreatingEvent`, so not yet `DocumentCreatedEvent`) and then do a query (see https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Query%20Module) to see if the space (matching the new document's space reference) matches an existing one or a deeper nested one inside the database... or
- check if the newly created document (`DocumentCreatedEvent`) has the name `WebHome` which would be much better in terms of performance, but it will not work if you are working with terminal documents (i.e. other documents than 'WebHome' ones, see https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/ContentOrganization/#HTerminology